# What is a flat rated engine?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, terminology

I've heard that a "Flat Rated Engine" is an engine where the power is reduced to keep the internal temperature within certain limits when the ambient temperature is above a certain point. Is that correct? How does it work?

Comment: well.. I didn't get clearly what is a flat rated engine and how does it work.

Comment: The engine doesn't measure OAT (at least not in general, some engines with FADEC can). Lower density air has less air running over the cooling part, which in aircraft are almost all air-cooled. The less air running over the parts affects cooling, so you have to reduce power to help keep the engine cool. A "flat rated" engine is rated to provide maximum take-off power through the entire climb. My 177-B is "flat rated" but I reduce power at 500' anyway to help cooling (and so I can close my cowl flaps).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a flat rated engine (my familiarity is with gas turbines, but the concept may apply to other engine types), is an engine for which the control system is designed to achieve the same level of thrust (hence the "flat" term), up to a certain OAT, then for higher ambient temperatures, the level of thrust decreases as a function of OAT, normally in a pretty linear fashion. This control system operation gives identical performance over the flat portion of the OAT range even while the engine degrades (until it degrades to the point it hits the EGT limit), making the plane performance predictable. But for higher OATs, it stops the EGT continuing to increase. The temperature at which the thrust starts to decrease is typically 25 or 30 deg C, and can be found in the EASA or [FAA engine type certificates](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet) (e.g. see section 6 of [this EASA one for the CFM56-5](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/EASA-TCDS-E.003_CFM_International_S.A._--_CFM56--5Band5C_series_engines-03-17122012.pdf)). See the graph from [this CFM56 document](https://www.metabunk.org/attachments/docslide-us_a-320-engine-pdf.16733/) below. So, your understanding was correct.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Flat rating is a concept by which an engine, as stated above is restricted, in terms of power or thrust output by the fuel control unit to produce a uniform power or thrust output as the aircraft climbs or descends until the ambient air conditions will not allow the engine to operate at or beyond the maximum thermodynamic output of the engine.  Like any other heat engine, the power or thrust produced by an aviation gas turbine (the gas core) depends on the available mass flow rate of working fluid (air in this case) as well as the operating temperature limits of the engine's hot section.  The maximum available power or thrust a gas core can produce at sea level at STP is referred to as the core's thermodynamic rating.  As an example, the Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6-66D turboshaft engine has a thermodynamic rating of 1,850 horsepower, but the FCU flat rates this to a constant maximum power output from the driveshaft to 850 ESHP, which remains available all the way up to approx FL260, thereafter decreasing with an increase in altitude.

Answer (score 2):

[This may be a good working definition](http://www.boeing-727.com/Data/engine/Flat%20Rating.html)

> **The Flat Rating Concept**
>
> The rating of a jet engine is the thrust performance that is
>   guaranteed by the manufacturer for a new engine under specific
>   operating conditions such as, take off, maximum continuous, climb,
>   cruise.
>
> Some non Prat and Whitney (P&W) engines are rated to a constant
>   compressor speed (RPM). P&W rates there engines to a constant exhaust
>   gas temperature (EGT). This is referred to as the flat rating concept.
>   To get your head around this concept you must understand the following
>   principle.
>
> The temperature and density of the ambient air vary inversely.
>
> Lower temperature = > Higher Density
>
> Higher Temperature = >Lower Density
>
> The amount of airflow (lbs/sec) through the engine is a function of
>   compressor speed and air density. It is greater when the compressor
>   speed and density are high.
>
> The compressor speed is a function of the energy available to the
>   compressors turbine. That energy comes from the combustion or air and
>   fuel, so the turbine turns faster when the fuel flow rate is greater.
>   The compressor speed is also a function of the airflow through the
>   compressor. Higher rates of air flow reduce the speed of the
>   compressor.
>
> The compressors rotational speed and the amount of airflow through the
>   compressor are independent, they affect each other though.
>
> The turbine inlet temperature is proportional to the energy available
>   to turn the turbine. The exhaust temperature is proportional to the
>   turbine inlet temperature. So a higher EGT corresponds to a larger
>   amount of energy to the turbine so it can turn the compressor faster.
>
> When EGT is held constant, or lowered the result is a prolonged hot
>   section life and at the same time provides the thrust to meet the
>   certification requirements.

Or a [bit more concise from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_rated)

> When an engine is Flat rated it means that an engine of high
>   Horsepower rating is constrained to a lower horsepower rating. The
>   engine output in this case will always remain the same, but when
>   atmospheric conditions such as high temperatures and high altitude
>   (Hot and High) reduce the power output of the engine it has more
>   headroom before it falls below the limited maximum output.

Comment: Just to check I understand, could it therefore be said that when atmospheric conditions are below ideal, the engine still performs to spec because it was previously limited by EGT and not atmospheric conditions?

Comment: @Notts90, almost. The engine always performs to spec, because spec just describes how the engine behaves. The point is that the performance is such that the engine produces the same thrust and power up to certain density altitude (above it the engine becomes RPM-limited and the power decreases).